# Freeform Pro showing error when uploading File of 9MB. How can I increase the upload file in freeform?

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

When I upload file to expression engine Freeform Pro 4.2.5. It shows me error.
[image]

How can I increase the size of the file? Or what can occur

Answer (score 2):

Does your php/apache config are set to accept large upload file ?
Ex. upload_max_filesize and post_max_size = XXM
Make sure they are larger than your file size..

Comment: This is likely the issue. These settings are in php.ini. If on Linux, you'd type "find / -name 'php.ini" to find it.